# Translating Sql to Linq

Tags: c#, linq

How to translate

```
select *from
   (
     select EmployeeID,FirstName,LastName,Region from Employees where city
     in ('London','Seattle') 
   )
   x
where x.Region is not null
```

into Linq Equivalent.

**I tried (But null values also get selected)**

```
LinqDBDataContext Context = new LinqDBDataContext();

   var query = from emps in

                  (
                       from empls in Context.Employees
                       where empls.City == "London" || empls.City == "Seattle"
                        && empls.Region != null
                             select new
                              {
                                 FirstName = empls.FirstName,
                                 LastName = empls.LastName,
                                 City = empls.City,
                                 Region = empls.Region
                              }
                   )
              select emps;


            GridView1.DataSource = query;
            GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Couldn't your query be simplied as follows:

select EmployeeID,FirstName,LastName,Region from Employees where city in ('London','Seattle') And Region IS NOT NULL

Comment: Yes it could be.I will correct it

Comment: I just ran your query through Linqer. Here is what it came up with:

from t in Employees
where
  (new string[] {"London", "Seattle" }).Contains(t.City) &&
  t.Region != null 
select new {
  t.EmployeeID,
  t.FirstName,
  t.LastName,
  t.Region
}

Comment: @Randy  Minder oh ! Thanks ,I will go for trial version then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It's your parentheses.  You're missing them around your City's OR statement.**

```
LinqDBDataContext Context = new LinqDBDataContext();

   var query = from emps in

                  (
                       from empls in Context.Employees
                       where (empls.City == "London" || empls.City == "Seattle")
                        && empls.Region != null
                             select new
                              {
                                 FirstName = empls.FirstName,
                                 LastName = empls.LastName,
                                 City = empls.City,
                                 Region = empls.Region
                              }
                   )
              select emps;


            GridView1.DataSource = query;
            GridView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 2):

Threadpool, you need to take a look at a product called Linqer (I have no association with it). It is fantastic. It converts SQL queries to LINQ. I have yet to come across a query it cannot handle.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your where clause to be:

where (empls.City == "London" || empls.City == "Seattle") && empls.Region != null

Without the parens you would get nulls with London

Answer (score 1):

Your sql can be reritten as:

```
select EmployeeID,FirstName,LastName,Region 
from Employees 
where city in ('London','Seattle') 
and Region is not null
```